# How will I change the id attribute according the condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the below snippet I'm changing the id attribute value of the `UPDATE` button. But while its id value is changed then according its change id why jQuery is not working well according `update` button `id` attribute.

```js
$('#save').click(function(){
  console.log(this.value);
  if(this.value == 1){
    $("#update").attr('id','update1');
  }
  else{
    $("#update").attr('id','update2');
  }
  console.log($('.update').attr("id"));
});
$('#update').click(function(){
  console.log($('.update').attr("id"));
  console.log("hello update");  
});
$('#update1').click(function(){
  console.log($('.update').attr("id"));
  console.log("hello update1");  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="textfield" type="text" placeholder="Enter">
<button id ="save" value= "1">save</button>
<button id ="update" class="update">Update</button>
```

How will I do it that When save button is clicked then `id` value is changed according its condition. And according the value of the `id` attribute of the **update button** how will Jquery works means if `id="update1"` then in `console.log` it will print "hello update1" else "update". Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the since the event is already attached to the DOM element, updating id and clicking on it is making no difference.

You can try by delegating the event using `on`

```js
$('#save').click(function() {
  console.log(this.value);
  if (this.value == 1) {
    $("#update").attr('id', 'update1');
  } else {
    $("#update").attr('id', 'update2');
  }
  console.log($('.update').attr("id"));
});
$('#update').click(function() {
  console.log($('.update').attr("id"));
  console.log("hello update");
});
$('body').on('click', '#update1', function() {  // changed here
  console.log($('.update').attr("id"));
  console.log("hello update1");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="textfield" type="text" placeholder="Enter">
<button id="save" value="1">save</button>
<button id="update" class="update">Update</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

@vikas kumar, try with below solution,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#save').click(function(){
  if(this.value == 1){
    $("#update").attr('id','update1');
  }
  else{
    $("#update").attr('id','update2');
  }
});
$('.update').click(function(){
   console.log($('.update').attr("id"));
   switch($('.update').attr("id"))
   {
     case "update":
     console.log("hello update");  
     break;
     case "update1":
     console.log("hello update1");  
     break;
     case "update2":
     console.log("hello update2");  
     break;
   } 
});

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="textfield" type="text" placeholder="Enter">
<button id ="save" value= "1">save</button>
<button id ="update" class="update">Update</button>
```

Comment: @vikaskumar, If you only change the ID of your DOM then just handle the single click event. Otherwise you need to manage as many click event as you give id to your update element. This is the safe and easiest way.